# DataSorter.java:18: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I've been attempting to work on a program for my AP java class and I've run in an issue where I have everything declared, it looks like everything has access to one another where i need it and my colleagues don't know either; here's what i have:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
    This is a test class for DataSet.
    */
    public class DataSorter
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
        {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter three numbers:");
         double num1 = in.nextDouble();
         double num2 = in.nextDouble();
         double num3 = in.nextDouble();
         DataSorter sorter = new DataSorter();



         System.out.println("The inputs in sorted order are:\n" + sorter.getSmallest() + "\n" + sorter.getMiddle() + "\n" + sorter.getLargest());
          }
   }
```

Here's class 2

```
   /**
   This class finds the smallest, middle, and largest of
   three numbers.
   */
   public class DataSet
   {
   /**
   Constructs a data set that processes three numbers.
   @param num1 the first number to sort
   @param num2 the second number to sort
   @param num3 the third number to sort
   */
   public DataSet(double num1, double num2, double num3)
   {
     num1 = dub1;
     num2 = dub2;
     num3 = dub3;

   }
    /**
    Gets the smallest number in the data set.
    @return smallest the smallest of three numbers
    */
   public double getSmallest()
  {
      double smallest = dub1;

      if(dub2 < smallest)
        smallest = dub2;

      if(dub3 < smallest)
        smallest = dub3;

      return smallest;

    }
    /**
    Gets the largest number in the data set.
    @return largest the largest of three numbers
    */
     public double getLargest()
     {
    double largest = dub1;

    if(dub2 > largest)
     largest = dub2;

    if(dub3 > largest)
     largest = dub3;

  return largest;

  }

  /**
  Gets the middle number in the data set.
  @retu rn mi ddl e the middle number of three numbers
  */
   public double getMiddle()
  {
       double middle = 0;

       middle = dub1 + dub2 + dub3 - getLargest() - getSmallest();

       return middle;


  }
   private double dub1;
   private double dub2;
   private double dub3;

 }
```

Comment: You _might_ want to help us and mark/highlight line 18.

Comment: Btw, there's no relation to microsoft or jgrasp in your question. It's plain Java.

Comment: Additional info: your `DataSet` constructor seems wrong. You're assigning fields to parameters (`num1 = dub1` etc.) instead of the other way round, which would be `dub1 = num1` etc. You'd see that faster if parameters where final btw.

Answer (score 1):

sorter is an object of class DataSorter. but it does not have methods getSmallest. its present in class2 (dataset)

you should make sorter object of Datase

> DataSet sorter = new DataSet(num3, num3, num3);